# При конвертации из .ui в .py ошибка: ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python

Вопрос в заголовке. Использую python 3.6.0 и PyQT5
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По вопросам на стаковерфлоу прошелся, ничего не помогло, python3.dll на месте, pyqt и python x64

Comment: А `Qt` - библиотеки _на месте_?

Comment: по крайней мере QT5Core.dll на месте, или про какую идет речь?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fy1ekg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил проблему переустановкой Python на x32 и версию 3.5.0. Видимо несовместимость с Python 3.6.0